# how to prevent each login from updating my token?

Tags: node.js, jwt

I have searched for an expiration time and assigned it to be 24 hours but every time I log in my token is changed, I want to avoid that.
I put it to expire in 24 hours but always update it every time I login

```
    app.post('/json/usuario',function(req,res,next){
    var request= new mssql.Request();
    var dni=req.body.dni;
    var password=req.body.password
    console.log(dni);
    console.log(password);
  var tokenData = {
        dni: dni
        // ANY DATA
      }

      var token = jwt.sign(tokenData, 'Secret Password', {
         expiresIn: 60 * 60 * 24
      })
 var consulta=" SELECT p.dni_Pro,a.fecha_Aso,foto,dbo.InitCap(isnull(p.nombres_Pro,'')+' '+ isnull(p.apellidoPat_Pro,'')+' ' +isnull(p.apellidoMat_Pro,''))as NombreCompleto,dbo.InitCap(a.nombre_Aso) as nombre_Aso,dbo.InitCap(r.nombre_Red) as nombre_Red,'estado'=case p.estado_pro when 'A'then 'Activo' when'P'then 'Pasivo' WHEN'N'THEN'Evaluación' when'F'then'Ex Socio(F)' when'E'then'Ex Socio(E)' when'R'then'EX SOCIO(R)' end,p.sexo_Pro,(select codigo_Cam  from Campana where estado_Cam ='A') campana,p.fechaNac_Pro,contraseña as contra " +
 " from Productor p inner join Asociacion a on a.codigo_Aso=p.codigo_Aso inner join red r on r.codigo_Red=a.codigo_Red where p.dni_Pro='"+dni+"' and codigoIng_Pro is not null "
    request.query(consulta, function(err,result){
        if(err){
            res.send({
                "code":400,
                "failed": err
            })
        }
        else{
            if (result.rowsAffected >0){
                var data={};
                data=result.recordset;
                console.log(data);


                var hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(password).digest('hex');
                console.log(hash)
                if(data[0].contra.toLowerCase()==hash){
                    res.send({"token":token,result: data, "code":100,
                    "status":"Inicio Exitoso"}); 
                }
                else
                {
                    res.send({
                        "code":200,
                        "status":"Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos"  
                    });
                }
            }
            else
            {  
                res.send({
                    "code":203,
                    "status":"Usuario No Existe "  
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I have searched for an expiration time and assigned it to be 24 hours but every time I log in my token is changed, I want to avoid that.
I put it to expire in 24 hours but always update it every time I login

Answer (score 0):

In token-based authentication, your login endpoint is really for checking against credentials and issuing a token to be used on validating access to other protected endpoints.

Just cache that token issued on login (i.e., if you're using JS for your front-end, `localStorage.token = token`), and use it for your protected endpoints.

Once your server returns an expired token error on a request, you can prompt the user to re-login and save the next one.

I suggest you read up on what parts go into a JWT token to better understand how they are composed.